# Springboot mysql + jpa communications link failure

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

I use mysql + jpa at Springboot

when I send first query to my server, then I didn't use my server for approximately 20 seconds. Finally my server throws mysql communication closed error then, I can't connect to my server.

I access to server with react-native app.

here's my error..

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 19,879 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 19,879 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1118) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]
```

and here's my application.yml file

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://connecturl/dbname?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true
    username: root
    password: ******
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

    tomcat:
      test-while-idle: true
      time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 15000
      validation-query: SELECT 1
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 10000000

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    generate-ddl: false
    show-sql: true
    database: mysql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
```

I found some errors with mysql lost connection. But all that errors occur when no connection to db with 8hours.

*ps my sql db's timeout setting is 28800

Comment: try `time-between-eviction-runs-millis=60000`?

Comment: I used the option with - time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 15000
This option means the interval time about execute  select 1 to my db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.

I use external IP when connect to Local( In same Network ) DB.

That's the reason.

I think it's because wifi router's problem.

Call internal network with external IP address(ex call 192.168.0.1 as 211.333.222.2) can cause DNS LoobBack issue.

So, you need to change setting at Router system to avail DNS Loopback.